# Use of TreatAsContent( ) function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, email-tracking

I am trying to understand TreatAsContent function? Can anyone please elaborate in simple words about this function and which scenarios it might be useful? like e.g. I have seen online mentions about tracking but still don't understand 100%.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is already quite well-described wherever you look.
The main use case of `TreatAsContent` is to ensure the ampscript placed in a variable gets parsed. Imagine this scenario:

I have a footer text, where I want to use personalisation. This footer text is fetched from the sendable data extension, where it is stored in *footer_text* field. Let's assume the text in the Data extension being: "Hi %%first_name%% - manage your account here". We are also assuming there is a *first_name* field in the sendable data extension.

In case I will just print the text using `%%=AttributeValue('footer_text')=%%`, the result would be:
**Hi %%first_name%% - manage your account here**

As you can see, the first_name is not replaced, as we are not expecting hence parsing the Ampscript.

Using `%%=TreatAsContent(AttributeValue('footer_text'))=%%` will give us a different result:
**Hi John - manage your account here**

And you are correct, the `TreatAsContent` can be used together with httpgetwrap for tracking purposes, but this approach has substantial limitations, and should only be used if you know what you are doing.